# load ajax response to a data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables-1.10

Using Data-table 1.10, I have 10000+ rows. I need to draw the table body using the ajax response. Now I am  returning the data as an array and iterating over the front-end in html which makes the data-table renders n number of rows irrespective of pagination and once the page is fully loaded it draws the default table(10 rows). I would like to remove the iterator and load the body from AJAX response. How to achieve it?

I am using data-table in rails4. I also tried using deferRender: true there is no change in my app

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Rathishkumar, Please checkout my answer, accept and up vote if it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> I really don't get it why are you iterating the `data[]` and rendering
>   the `dataTable body`!

You can simply use [Ajax sourced data](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) in dataTable as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );
```

There is also [server side pagination supported in dataTable](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html), this is known as server side processing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

This is the list of [Server side processing Parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) sent in an Ajax call.

The embedded links has well documentation and examples to help you. Your API has to serve the JSON payload in the required format as shown in the examples.

Hope this helps, let me know if you need further assistance!

Comment: from the controller am creating an array as json format and am iterating over the array to draw the table i know its costliest operation but i do not know how to draw the table as json itself on successful ajax response?.
Could you help on that??

Comment: Sure, I can help you. Please update your question with the following details: 1. Show me the `js/html` code how you are drawing the table? 2. Show me your `json` payload that is sent from API. 3. Have you gone through DataTables API doc, especially all the links I have provided?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/ae7ua9wh/] need to load the tbody with the ajax response how to do it??